# multiples joins a una misma tabla

Tags: sql, join

Necesito hacer una consulta a 3 tablas, albaranes, clientes y una tercera donde se guardan campos adicionales de los clientes.
La estructura de esta última es **cliente** **campo** **valor**, esto es, a que cliente pertenece, que campo queremos y su valor.
Esto tenía pensado realizarlo mediante `joins` a la misma tabla (tantos como campos a recuperar).
Cabe decir que en el ejemplo recupero menos valores de los que en realidad hay en la consulta, para sintetizar:

```
select      cab.NUMERO [Numero],
            CLI.NOMBRE [Entidad Destino],
            cab.FECHA Fecha,
            campo1.valor [campo1],
            campo2.valor [campo2],
            campo3.valor [campo3],
            campo4.valor [campo4]
            from  cabecera as CAB
            left join clientes as CLI ON CAB.CLIENTE = cli.CODIGO
            left join campAdicional as campo1 on  campo1.CODIGO = CAB.CLIENTE AND campo1.CAMPO = '001'
            left join campAdicional as campo2 on  campo2.CODIGO = CAB.CLIENTE AND campo2.CAMPO = '002'
            left join campAdicional as campo3 on  campo3.CODIGO = CAB.CLIENTE AND campo3.CAMPO = '003'
            left join campAdicional as campo4 on  campo4.CODIGO = CAB.CLIENTE AND campo5.CAMPO = '004'
```

Al ejecutar esta consulta, el resultado es el correcto, pero tarda muchísimo teniendo muy pocos datos de prueba, lo cual me hace suponer que no estoy enfocando esto de la manera correcta.
He intentado adicionar los campos adicionales de la tabla **campAdicional** mediante un `Union`, pero con este no puedo acceder a la cabecera del primer `select`.

¿Alguien me puede echar un cable por favor?

Comment: sin ver indices y ejemplos mas claros, mas un explain plan, imposible saber porque anda lento...

Comment: Soy consciente, pero a pesar de eso, crees que es la manera adecuada de recuperar esos campos adicionales? me refiero a hacer tantos Joins a la misma tabla.

Comment: Y si los datos estan guardados de esa forma extraña, que otra cosa podrias hacer?

Comment: Es un ERP comercial, supongo que se hace así para no tocar las tablas maestras.
Muchas gracias, veré a ver que hago.

Comment: No.. si es un ERP es para que se pueda hacer cualquier cosa, sin tener que tocar el codigo (es como WordPress, lo hacen a proposito)... Entonces, lo mas probable, es que tegnas que mover esos datos a otras bases ya arreglados si vas a tener que hacer el query seguido.. pero estoy hablando sin saber NADA DE NADA DE TU ESCENARIO...

Comment: No hay forma de que, así como puedes correr este select, obtengas la info de cómo están definidas esas tres tablas? (Y que pongas esa info aquí en la pregunta?). Puede ser tan simple como que falta un índice y esté haciendo un full scan en alguna parte, pero todo son adivinanzas hasta ver la definición de las tablas, los índices que tienen y demás.

Comment: Complicado, excepto la tabla de campos adicionales, las tablas son bastante extensas, como para replicar la estructura aquí.
De todas maneras, los indices parecen estar todos correctamente y les he hecho rebuild a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto lo podrías hacer con un solo `JOIN` varias expresiones `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    cab.NUMERO [Numero],
    cli.NOMBRE [Entidad Destino],
    cab.FECHA Fecha,
    MIN(CASE
            WHEN c.campo = '001' THEN c.valor
        END) Campo1,
    MIN(CASE
            WHEN c.campo = '002' THEN c.valor
        END) Campo2,
    MIN(CASE
            WHEN c.campo = '003' THEN c.valor
        END) Campo3,
    MIN(CASE
            WHEN c.campo = '004' THEN c.valor
        END) Campo4
FROM dbo.cabecera cab
LEFT JOIN dbo.clientes cli
    ON cab.Cliente = cli.Codigo
LEFT JOIN dbo.campAdicional c
    ON  c.CODIGO = cab.Cliente --AND campo1.CAMPO = '001'
GROUP BY 
    cab.NUMERO,
    cli.NOMBRE,
    cab.FECHA
;
```

Comment: Eso me cuadriplica los resultados, ya que me muestra un registro por cada campAdicional.CAMPO al no filtrarlo en el Join.

Comment: No he dicho nada, funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: Una pregunta  @Lamak, usando la solución que me sugeriste, ¿Cómo puedo evaluar dentro de "WHEN c.campo = '002'"si "WHEN c.campo ='001'" tenia valor para mostrar c.valor o mostrar un string vacio?  disculpa y muchas gracias.